# How to enable Local Machine debug in Visual Studio UWP?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, uwp

I've downloaded existing UWP project and I wanna to start it on local machine in Visual Studio. But now I only can debug on Device or Remote machine.
How can I add local machine debug mode to the project?

Comment: Did you install Win10 SDK? Otherwise you need to reinstall VS. The `Local Machine` option is listed in debug option.

Comment: @Vincent yes, Windows 10 SDK (10.0.18362.0) is installed. There isn't `Local Machine ` in debug option.

Comment: If you create a new blank uwp app, can it run on local machine? In addition, are you building x86 or ARM?

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT I've changed building platform from ARM to x64 in exiting project and `Local Machine` option appears. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When You build for ARM, then it can only run on an ARM device, so it only shows the Device or Remote machine options. If you want to debug the project on local machine, you can click the drop down to build x86 or x64.